# Combine arrays and output to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append

There are 2 arrays with variables, you need to combine them, create button elements with the *btn-menu* class, data element *category* (with a variable from the array), and text from the array.

```
let category = ['Pizza ', 'Rolls ', 'Sets ', 'Hot dish', 'Salads'];
let slug_id = ['pizza', 'rolls', 'sets', 'hot-dish', 'salads'];
```

The order of the first and second arrays corresponds to the content, that is, ***Pizza (0)** and **pizza(0)*** need to output all these elements to the HTML **nav** object with the *container* class.

You should get a horizontal menu with buttons:

```
<nav class="container">
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="pizza">Pizza </button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="rolls">Rolls </button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="sets">Sets </button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="hot-dish">Hot dish</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="salads">Salads </button>
</nav>
```

You need the code in js or jQuery. Please help me solve the problem :)

Here's what I tried:

```
var category = ['Pizza ', 'Rolls ', 'Sets ', 'Hot dish', 'Salads'];
var slug_id = ['pizza', 'rolls', 'sets', 'hot-dish', 'salads'];

var nav = $('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
    var btn = $('<button/>');
    var class_btn = $(btn).attr('class','btn-menu ripple-btn');
    var text_btn = $(class_btn).text(category[i]);
 }
$(btn).appendTo(nav);
```

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this coursework. SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you

Comment: You just need a `for` loop over one of the arrays, using the index to get the corresponding value from the other array, then you can use those values in a template string.

Comment: Added the code that I write, but I only output one value and I do not know how to add a second array :(

Answer (score 1):

As you are already iterating through the array and length of both array are same simply you can use `$(btn).attr('category', slug_id[i]);` this will add array value at `i` position on every iterating inside button.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var category = ['Pizza ', 'Rolls ', 'Sets ', 'Hot dish', 'Salads'];
var slug_id = ['pizza', 'rolls', 'sets', 'hot-dish', 'salads'];

var nav = $('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {

  var btn = $('<button/>');
  $(btn).attr('class', 'btn-menu ripple-btn');
  $(btn).text(category[i]);
  $(btn).attr('category', slug_id[i]); //use this to add attribute with value from array
  $(btn).appendTo(nav); //add button created inside nav
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="container">
</nav>
```